# pandoc 2.1 task-list do not render in docx

Tags: docx, pandoc

Is there a way to create a task-list that prints in docx format? I am using the `[ ] task-list` and `[x] completed-task` syntax, with the following filters:

```
-r markdown+smart+implicit_figures+table_captions+pipe_tables+latex_macros+compact_definition_lists+subscript+superscript+yaml_metadata_block+raw_tex+fenced_code_attributes+line_blocks+backtick_code_blocks+fenced_code_blocks+link_attributes+tex_math_dollars+native_spans
```

This seems to working html (when I view it via the preview app [Marked2](http://marked2app.com/), but I cannot get it to work when converting from `markdown` to `docx`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain pandoc does not support task lists. However, you can use a filter to add support. Have a look at the [task-list filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/task-list) in the semi-official filter collection.  You can use it by adding it to you directory and calling pandoc with an additional `--lua-filter=task-list.lua` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

As of pandoc 2.6, task lists are supported.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It pays to stay up to date with the new features of releases.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an older version (e.g. 2.2.1 currently in Debian Buster), you can use this workaround with a Latex math environment:

```
- $\Box$ Task 1
- $\Box$ Task 2
```

Alternatively, you can use $\square$ as well, but this renders smaller boxes for me. This only works for unchecked boxes, e.g., in case you want to print the list and check the tasks with a pen.